# How can I read a text file containing json data with jade and then pass this data to my custom APIs?

Tags: node.js, pug

```
    form#uploadForm(enctype='multipart/form-data', action='../update', method='post', target='_blank')
        input(type='file', name='userPhoto')
        input(type='submit', value='function', name='submit')
```

I am able to select the file with above code but I cant read the file and pass the data further to my APIs(written in node)

Answer (score 0):

Your pug code is not a problem. You now have to use a multipart module to handle your file upload server-side, for example, express and bodyParser:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/update', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files); // here you can handle files you received
});
```